# How to give Microphone permission to Java application (macOS Mojave and above)?

Tags: java, swift, xcode, command-line

I have created an executable file in xcode (swift 4+). I have added microphone permission within the project (.plist file) and i have also asked for the permission on runtime: here is the code:

```
switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .audio) {
    case .authorized:
        audioStarter.staticMode()

    case .notDetermined:
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .audio) { granted in
            if granted {
                print("Permission granted")
                audioStarter.staticMode()
            }
        }

    case .denied:
        print("Permission denied")
        exit(0)

    case .restricted:
        print("This user cannot access microphone")
        exit(0)
    }
```

This executable works fine if i run it via terminal (it shows microphone permission popup and works absolutely fine). But when i run this exec file from Java Process it doesn't show permission to access microphone and thus the exec file doesn't work. Here is the sample code in java:

```
String cmd = getBinPath() + "./audio_service -r";
        try {
            final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String response = scanner.nextLine ();
                System.out.println(response);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Hi did you find solution? I am badly stuck on the same problem. I got two systems Mac OS Catalina. Java doesn't ask permission on  both systems. However on one system I am able to access Microphone and able to record while on another it is not able to detect sound in mic. Please share if you got solution.

Comment: Hi. I added info.plist file in my xcode project and added microphone dependency (permission) in it. After that it show up the microphone permission popup.